# Interfacing IOT- GA6 to Arduino

Tags: communication, gsm, sms

Good evening guys,

Looking for any help on interfacing the above GSM/GPRS module with arduino.

Connections:

VCC and GND of module- separate power supply, 5v 3A

URX to pin 2
UTX to pin 3

Common GND between arduino and separate supply.

Tried AT command code for A6 module, getting +CREG:3 on serial monitor.

Same connections as above with GSM send messages code example on arduino-

Doesn't go past "Sms messages sender

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to interface the ga6 module with arduino. I saw some posts say you must flash the module to A6

Comment: Also is there a GA6 module code I could use

Comment: Would this help: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/EasyMades/a6-gsm-gprs-module-at-commands-34835a